# Magento 2 : How to Import Additional Attributes and Images

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, import

I am trying to import csv in Magento 2. There are no errors given by Magento while importing, but column `additional_attributes` is totally ignored and `additional_images` is ignored if it contains multiple values. I used following import options:

> Field divider: ,
>
> Value divider: |
>
> Fields enclosure: active

The csv looks like, this:

```
sku,additional_attributes,additional_images
123,"manufacturer=ABC,material=Wood|Metal,color=red","2.png,3.png"
```

Why are those values getting ignored?

Edit: If I deactivate the fields enclosure checkfield I receive the following error:

```
1. Value for 'manufacturer' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1
```

The values equals exactly the value specified for that attribute in the backend.

SOLUTION: I replaced al the `|` with a `,` in my csv except for the `additional_attributes` column. During the import I used the default configuration, both delimiters as `,` field enclosure checkbox unchecked. Now it is working.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Otherwise this question looks as if it were still open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION: I replaced all the `|` with a `,` in my csv except for the `additional_attributes` column. During the import I used the default configuration, both delimiters as `,` and field enclosure checkbox unchecked. Now it is working.